How do I create a nested select/CTE in sqlalchemy
I want to select a user based on the number of photo's they have (which are child elements). But when I try to do:
import sqlalchemy as sa

sa.select(User).where(sa.func.count(User.photos) == 1)

However, that does not work because COUNT is an aggregate function. I read that I can fix this problem by using either a nested SELECT (subquery) or a WITH clause (CTE). So my first question is which one should I use:
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT user.id, user.email, user.photos, COUNT(user.photos) AS photos_count FROM users
) AS inner_table
WHERE photos_count = 1

or:
WITH inner_table AS (
    SELECT user.id, user.email, user.photos, COUNT(user.photos) AS photos_count FROM users 
)
SELECT * FROM inner_table WHERE photos_count = 1

Firstly, are these correct and actually the way to solve my problem and secondly, how do I convert these into sqlalchemy. There is documentation on how to create a CTE and subquery in sqlalchemy but they seem to use the JOIN clause and not really do what I want to do.

Use .having() instead of .where(), just like in SQL.

Then the sql becomes: SELECT user.id, user.fotos... FROM user  HAVING count(laadpalen.id = fotos.laadpaal_id) = %(count_1)s
But that gives me the error (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) missing FROM-clause entry for table "fotos"
If I add Foto to the from:
select(User, Foto).having(func.count(User.fotos) == int(search))
Then it gives me the error:
(psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "user.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
And even if I then add the group_by clause it no longer errors but i just gives me very random stuff.

When you use count you have to specify the grouping. The raw SQL would be SELECT * FROM user GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1. I don't know the equivalent SQLAlchemy.
